# Pass environment variable to instance of WCF service

Tags: wcf, parameters, instance

I have a WCF service running on different environments. Which environment to run is application setting in config file.

Recently I started covering project with unit tests and got into an issue with changing environment variable. I don't want to change it manually every time, so I have to pass this environment to service somehow.

I register service with next code:

```
 Host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:1111/"));
 Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
```

Without changing servicebehaviour, instance of class is created on demand by default constructor. And I don't want to change servicebehaviour.

Currently I use static variable to pass this environment. Is there any better way to pass environment to instance of class?

Thanks.